# How can I access firebase custom claims from a cloud function

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

EDIT:
I can do it as below but I would prefer a nicer solution:

```
console.log((operatorUser.customClaims as any)['admin']);
console.log((operatorUser.customClaims as any).admin);
```

---

I am trying to check a users custom claim in a callable cloud function.

I am following the example from here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk

It has the error below when trying to access the custom claims:

"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"admin"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
  Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'Object'"

```
 const operatorUser = await admin.auth().getUser(operatorUserDoc.id);
 console.log(operatorUser.customClaims['admin']);
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "nicer solution"?  Custom claims can contain any valid JSON.  You will need to know what you put in there in order to understand what can come out.

Comment: By nicer solution I mean not having to convert the custom claims object to type "any".  I think it is more an issue with my tslint settings (I am using the default).  Hence I tagged typescript as well.  Functionally it is working ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type signature of `customClaims` was improved recently. If you're using the latest version of the SDK you should be able to just do `user['key']` to access claims.

See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/864 for more context.

Comment: I believe this solves the problem I had.  I will mark as a solution once I have confirmed or if someone else confirms it works.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks. this helped me with another related issue.

FYI, another way to access claims of the invoking user in a firebase "realtime db" cloud function is directly from the context.auth:

```
const isAdmin = (context?.auth?.token as any)?.admin;
```

- but unlike the update to the customClaims, the token attribute still needs to be cast. Also, keep in mind context.auth is only set on Firebase Realtime db, and is undefined on Firestore db functions.

Comment: *context* is provided only if you use callable functions.